# Missing record in a complex SELECT FULL JOIN statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, join

I created a SQL statement that should return the number of appointments receive by all salesmen. I work with 3 tables, `Contract, Salesmen` and `Appointment`, and I need to show how many appointments was received by each salesmen.

My problem is that although I use a Full Join the result doesn't show people who didn't receive any appointments. I found that there is a problem about constraint.

I took a look to Except, Intercept and Union option but none of those could solve my problem. Which other way could I use to get the full list of reps having or not received some appointments?

There is an example of the statement I used:

```
SELECT C.RepID, COUNT(A.AppID) AS AppAttrib, C.AppointmentPurchased, S.Name, S.FirstName
FROM Repartition.dbo.Contract C 
FULL JOIN Repartition.DBO.Appointment A
ON C.RepID = A.RepID
LEFT JOIN Repartition.DBO.Salesmen S
ON S.RepID = C.RepID
GROUP BY C.RepID, V.Nom, S.Name, S.FirstName
```

Thanks for your help,

Antenor

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your table structure in detail, I'm just guessing here - but I think your query starts at the wrong place - you should start with the `Salesmen` table, and go from there. So basically, select those columns from the `Salesmen` table that you need, and then join in the other tables as needed.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
     s.RepID, S.Name, S.FirstName, 
     COUNT(A.AppID) AS AppAttrib, 
     C.AppointmentPurchased 
FROM  
     Repartition.dbo.Salesmen s
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Repartition.dbo.Contract c ON s.RepID = c.RepID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Repartition.dbo.Appointment a ON s.RepID = a.RepID
GROUP BY 
     s.RepID, s.Name, s.FirstName
```